# Expression Blend crashes on MultiBinding for TextDecorations

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, expression-blend, multibinding

xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="SampleText">
    <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource sampleMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
</TextBlock>
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return TextDecorations.Underline;
}
```

In vs2010 all works fine and shows underlined text in designer as like as in running app. When I made it in project I working on now, Blend showed exception: http://s19.postimage.org/3wdr4htc3/Blend_Error.png

I've made a sample project demonstrating this behavior http://goo.gl/lnZ1T but for this project Blend only shows error, not exception.

Am I do something wrong or it's Blend's problem? Is there workaround?

Comment: Based on the exception it sounds like Blend thinks TextDecorations is not a dependency property, but obviously that's not the case. I have no explanation other than that. Sounds like a Blend bug.